# Desktop file won't open unless adminstrator

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I'm trying to open the GUI client for a cloud storage program pCloud. When I click the menu icon it doesn't open but when I open the desktop configuration file as an administrator in `/usr/share/applications` it runs. When it runs as administrator it won't sync with my computer files, which I'm assuming is because it doesn't have the permissions.

Using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: https://www.linuxbabe.com/cloud-storage/install-pcloud-drive-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: The drive will connect but I cannot open the GUI client will not open. This means I cannot enter my password to a folder and therefore cannot access it when syncing.

Comment: So, which parts of the installation process have you botched?

Comment: The instructions on linuxbabe.com refer to a pcloud*.deb file, but the current version of the download for 64 bit Linux is no longer a *.deb file. The current instructions from pCloud tell you to change the properties of the download file to make it executable, but Ubuntu still doesn't recognise it as an application.